# I can't figure out what's wrong with comparing array indexes

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, sum, integer

I need to compare array indexes, not their meanings. I'm a newbie in java at all, and wrote this code and can't understand what exactly I'm doing wrong. Pls hlp.

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numOfPeople = new int[15];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPeople.length; i++) {
        numOfPeople[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        
    int sum2 = 0;
    int sum1 = 0;
    
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        sum2 = sum2 + numOfPeople[i];
    } else if (i % 2 != 0) {
        sum1 = sum1 + numOfPeople[i];
    }
    
    if (sum2 > sum1) {
        System.out.println("В домах с четными номерами проживает больше жителей.");
    } else if (sum2 < sum1) {
        System.out.println("В домах с нечетными номерами проживает больше жителей.");
    } else {
        System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Look like you have problem with variable scopes not with array indices. Variables sum1 and sum2 are defined within loop, so they 'reset' their value on each iteration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see my comments. Make sure you close the scanner and assign the variables outside the loop. I am not sure when you want the evaluation to take place, but it seems like it should not happen on every loop. I think you only want the end result, no?

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numOfPeople = new int[15];

    //I think you want these to be available outside the loop and not modified every iteration of the loop
    int sum2 = 0;
    int sum1 = 0;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPeople.length; i++) {

      //I added this just to help you see the iteration
      System.out.println("You must enter the value for index i: " + i);
      numOfPeople[i] = scanner.nextInt();


      //I think you mean to know if the index is even or odd here 
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        sum2 = sum2 + numOfPeople[i];
      } else if (i % 2 != 0) {
        sum1 = sum1 + numOfPeople[i];
      }
    } // I think you want to close the loop here, because you do not want this evaluated every time you go to a new index, but rather at the end?
    scanner.close();
    if (sum2 > sum1) {
      System.out.println("Even has more occupancy");
    } else if (sum2 < sum1) {
      System.out.println("Odd has more occupancy");
    } else {
      System.out.println();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: _Make sure you close the scanner_ - no, don't do that!

Comment: @rzwitserloot -The scanner should be closed after the loop is complete to avoid a resource leak. There is no more system input so the resource should be closed. Perhaps it would be different if this was not a main method and there were more inputs. Is there a reason you would recommend not to close it?

Comment: No. `System.in` is not a resource you should ever close. "To prevent a resource leak" applies only to resources you create. Scanner is not ITSELF a resource. The thing it wraps around, that is.

Comment: I assert that OP has a use case that is a perfect example of a time when it is safe (and good practice) to close the `System.in` resource. It is good practice to close unneeded resources.
I would refer you to the Java Documentation's examples:
[Java17Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)
We should keep in mind that any unused resource left open is accessible, and can represent a security concern. We should balance good practice with ensuring we do not prematurely close a resource. Resource leaks apply to more things than memory.
*link

Comment: _It is good practice to close unneeded resources._ -- this is incorrect.

Comment: You close all resources you're responsible for closing. You don't close resources you're not responsible for. You should always know which ones you are responsible for (_generally_, if you call the constructor, you are. If the method name includes the name `new`, such as `Files.newInputStream`, you are. But that's not quite complete, e.g. `socket.getInputStream` also infers responsibility to you). Scanner.in is not one of those. You do not have responsibility to close it, period. You close `System.in` when you intend to do that (e.g. you want piped-in senders to wrap it up). Period.